# UIView resize inside a UITableViewCell not displaying unless table is scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I got a `UIView` inside a `UITableViewCell` (dynamic prototype, not sure if it's important to clarify that) with a `background color` and changed the `view's frame` with the following code (inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method):

```
UIView* verde = (UIView*) [cell viewWithTag:202];
verde.frame =CGRectMake(20, 30, x, y);
```

The problem is that when the `UITableView` is drawn for the first time (when the screen loads) the `UIView` has the original size (established by default on the original prototype from the storyboard). But when I scroll down, the cell leaves the screen, therefore reused by another cell. When scrolling back to the cell, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called again and now the frame has the correct size.

I've tried calling `[verde setNeedsDisplay];` after changing the frame without success.

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: Can you put `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code?

Comment: Disabling Auto Layout solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling autolayout solved the issue as pointed out by Timothy Moose. Somehow the cells in the first draw (screen first load) retain the layout specified in the storyboard, when they leave screen and they are reused or created again the views are finally drawn with the correct frame.

Comment: is there another solution that doesn't require disabling autolayout?

Comment: How do you programatically disable auto layout?

Comment: Disabling autolayout solved my issue (caused by autolayout interfering when the UIView where first created), maybe manipulating the frame after the view is created might also solve the issue but disabling autolayout got the job done @Oren

Comment: I've never disabled autolayout programatically, only in XCode @Unome

Comment: Interesting. Where in XCode do you do that?

Comment: Well, you can google it and find out in a matter of seconds... Anyway check out [this link](http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/) @Unome

Comment: @ Fdo, Thank you, that helped + 1, and yes I did google it, but obviously didn't look very well.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this , Hope you can resolve the issue**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    else{
      [[cell.contentView viewWithTag: 202] removeFromSuperview];
    }

   UIView *view =[[UIView alloc]init];   
   view.frame = cell.contentView.frame;        
   view.tag = 202;

   view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];//To be sure that the custom view in the cell  
    [cell addSubview:view];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the debugging idea, it was a good one. Disabling Autolayout solved the issue.